# Restkit mapping POST Response

Tags: objective-c, ios, post, restkit

I am trying to map a POST response via the code below, but when the didLoadObjects is reached Restkit is trying to map the same object as I am trying to POST (POSTing a Foo and want it to map Bar, but RestKit is trying to map the return to Foo).

```
[self.objectManager sendObject:mySyncInstance toResourcePath:url usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader* postLoader) {
        postLoader.delegate = aDelegate;
        postLoader.objectMapping = [self.objectManager.mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[Bar class]];
        postLoader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
        postLoader.userData = kUserDefaultsAttendanceReads;
        postLoader.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
        postLoader.serializationMapping
        [postLoader setUsername:[prefs objectForKey:kCurrentUsername]];
        [postLoader setPassword:[prefs objectForKey:kCurrentPassword]];
    }];// end sendObject
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set rootKeyPath.

```
myPostReturnMapping.rootKeyPath = @"persons";

"persons": [
                        { "id": "1",
                          "firstname": "hans",
                          "lastname": "maier",
                          "genre": "m"
                        },
                        { "id": "2",
                          "firstname": "michael",
                          "lastname": "schmidt",
                          "genre": "w"
                        }]
```